# How do I boot my Mac pro using an HD with Windows 7 already installed?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mac, high-definition

I've inserted an HD from a Dell with Windows 7 already installed, how do I get my Mac Pro to boot using that HD without having to reinstall Windows?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Hold down <kbd>option</kbd> while booting, then select your Windows install from the EFI display.

Comment: Pretty sure you'd need to use Boot Camp to install appropriate drivers first, no?

Comment: What I -think- I know about this is that those drivers should have no impact on being able to boot the system in the first place. Boot Camp is really just the name Apple gives to the utilities that can -help- install Windows by repartitioning your drive, and the drivers that allow Windows to fully support your hardware.

In other words, I'm pretty sure you can just boot cold and then install the drivers later to get full support of the I/O up to speed.